Can YouTube notification list be opened in a separate tab in a browser?
When viewing YouTube in a browser on a desktop or a notebook, is it possible to open the notification list in a separate tab for a more convenient exploiting? Right clicking the bell icon doesn't give you an "Open link in new tab" option, but maybe there's still a way to achieve this goal, via some browser extension or the like.

A solution might look similar to https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions as https://www.youtube.com/feed/notifications, but that's probably a feature request to Google.
